# How do I format code from the web using Vim?

Tags: vim

For example, to render:

```
while (head == tail) { head++; a[head] = 0 }
```

into

```
while (head == tail)
{
    head++;
    a[head] = 0
}
```

Comment: check [clang format tool](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html). I think it is well suited for this job

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Firstly, you need a semicolon before the last `}` in order for this to be valid C; the semicolon should be thought of as terminating statements in C, rather than as separating statements.  Smart automatic indentation may not work properly unless you add that semicolon.)

Vim's `=` command (`:help =`) can be used to run code through an automatic indentation program, though it requires some configuration.  The basic idea is that you set the `equalprg` option (`:help 'equalprg'`) to a program that applies the indentation you want, and then use `=` in command mode to run it.  `=` works like other Vim motion-based commands such as `d` and `y`; for example, `==` indents the current line, `=ap` indents a paragraph, or you can use a visual range: `ggVG=` indents the whole file.

Now, by default, `equalprg` is set to the empty string, which only does basic per-line indentation built into Vim.  To do the kind of thing you're asking for, the best tool for the job is `indent`:

[indent](http://packages.ubuntu.com/indent) [image: Install indent]

`indent` has a vast array of options for various indentation styles; by default it uses the GNU coding style, but you'll probably want to customise it to suit your project's preferences.  See
[man indent](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/indent.1.html) for details.  To include spaces in the value of `equalprg`, you need to quote them with a backslash, so for example if you wanted to use K&R indentation style you would use `:set equalprg=indent\ -kr`.

You can also have the '=' command choose the appropriate indentation based on the file type, by using `:filetype indent on` - type `:help filetype` within vim for more info.

`:set autoindent` will tell vim to indent as you type. Adding either of these commands (minus the leading ':') to your ~/.vimrc file will make them permanent.

Answer (score 1):

This vim plugin uses external formatters to format code within vim. It's therefore stronger than vim's indentation machinery.

[vim-autoformat on GitHub](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat)

Answer (score 0):

Like any other text editor, VIM doesn't do that automatically.

Open a file with vim, press <kbd>i</kbd> for insert, and now you can edit freely, when done press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit insert mode and then to close and save the document write `:wq` for write, quit.